# Many readonly properties, when do I initialise them?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, properties

I have a class which has 5 properties which should not be modified by other classes (and subclasses with more of these). I want to make these properties readonly, but I would then have to write a monster `-init...` to supply values for all these properties.
Of course I could edit the ivars directly, but I don't want to fetch the values in the constructor, as I want to pull those values from the StackExchange API. Separating this into a factory class seems more appropriate here.

**tl;dr:** How to initialise readonly properties from a factory class without an abnormally long constructor?

It might be a design error. If so, please add an answer suggesting a different approach, because the point of this project is to learn about design.

Comment: Please be a little more concrete in your example. What kind of factory class initializes what kind of objects? Factory classes are not really common in Objective-C, so maybe that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Just do readonly in the .h, readwrite in the .m. Seems like what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the factory class to have the ability to update generally `readonly` properties and you want to avoid exceptionally long `init` method with a dizzying array of parameters, the typical solution in Objective-C is inelegant, but consists of defining a .h class category (used only by the factory class) that exposes the otherwise private or `readonly` properties.

For example, consider your `CustomObject` defined like so:

```
//  CustomObject.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger identifier; // public interface is readonly

@end
```

The implementation would define a private class extension that makes it clear that it's really `readwrite` even thought the public interface is `readonly`:

```
//  CustomObject.m

#import "CustomObject.h"

@interface CustomObject ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSUInteger identifier; // it's really readwrite and setter will be synthesized, too

@end


@implementation CustomObject

@end
```

You can then define category header, that will be used only by the factory class, that exposes the fact that the `CustomObject` property of `identifier` is `readwrite`:

```
//  CustomObject+Factory.h

#import "CustomObject.h"

@interface CustomObject (Factory)

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSUInteger identifier;

@end
```

If you look at `<UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>` you'll see a slightly different application of the same concept, in which they expose the notion that the `state` property is `readwrite` (whereas it otherwise appears to be `readonly`).

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, so I'll try it later today, but it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in that case, you would make them publicly readonly, but privately readwrite. You can do so by adding a class extension (nameless category at the top of your .m), where you redefine the property without the readonly classifier.

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger myProperty;
@end


// MyClass.m
@interface MyClass () // Note the ()
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger myProperty;
@end
```

Now, within your class you can write the property, but outsiders can only read it.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but a factory class would be an outsider.

Comment: @11684: Then unless I misunderstand your question, you don't really want those properties to be readonly..?

Comment: Only the factory should be able to modify them. But if you say I shouldn't make them readonly in that case, I'll take that advice. Please read the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: @11684 this is correct. A typical pattern for receiving data from an API would be for a class to have a method like `updateWithDictionary:`.  The data class would parse out the data, assign it to the properties, which could then be read only outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it both ways. To my knowledge, Objective-C does not have the concept of "friend" members, meaning members that are accessible to only certain classes. Therefore, your only choice is to create public read-only properties and set their values in the constructor. In essence, your class could be treated as immutable. Yes, the init method may get quite long, but blame that on Objective-C's verbosity for such things. It's still the correct design choice.

MyClass.h:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (copy, readonly, nonatomic) NSString *value1;
@property (assign, readonly, nonatomic) NSInteger value2;

- (instancetype)initWithValue1:(NSString *)value1 value2:(NSInteger)value2;

@end
```

MyClass.m:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (instancetype)initWithValue1:(NSString *)value1 value2:(NSInteger)value2
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _value1 = value1;
        _value2 = value2;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

You may also want to consider using JetBrains' [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) product, as it has refactoring tools that might help with creating init methods from properties (although I haven't done this myself).

Answer (score 0):

You can make constructor with only one parameter (NSArray or NSDictionary, dictionary seems less preferred because of keys), and send all 5 properties values in defined order or with defined key (as you will initialize you objects only in factory you will need to carry about correct order only in one place). In this case, if number of properties grows will be no needs to rename constructor method and adding more and more parameter names.
Also, you can simply use `setVale:forKey:` method, whith no matter is property readonly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches, and you may be trying to force these two into one model (physical object):

1) If the base provides the storage (e.g. ivars), then the values belong in the initializer. Simple as that - do guarantee the values are readonly for your sanity.

2) Lazy initialization. Your post suggests this is ideal for execution. The answer to this is that storage is an implementation detail. Let your ivars be stored by the class, and written when loaded.

Really, you want to reuse your programs and avoid making monstrous hierarchies and relying on inheritance for reuse. Consider how your 5 properties may be abstracted -- this would be by one or multiple helper classes (e.g. which provide these properties) which adopt a common protocol of the properties they vend. In this way, you may load lazily, copy, use initialization, or a number of other approaches.

Then your "subclasses" would just have a property which contains one of these objects which represents the "Base 5 Properties". Subclasses would not need 5 parameters. They would only need an `id<MonBase5Properties>` parameter. Again, an implementation (which adopts the protocol) may store the properties, and another may load them on demand. Either way, it's a convenient way to pack up a common set of data or interface into a type (class or protocol).